# Adding labels to graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics

Maybe not a very descriptive title, but I wasn't sure how to pin it down. What I have is an array of vectors, a numerical example of which would be

```
vectors = 
  {{0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5}, 
   {0.707107, 1.60288*10^-15, -0.707107, 0.}, 
   {2.11636*10^-15, -0.707107, 4.996*10^-16, 0.707107}, 
   {-0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5}}
```

What I then do is plot these in a circular fashion, on a disk

```
EVDisk[vec_, vn_, x_, y_, θ0_, θ1_] := 
 Graphics[{
   Which[
     Sign[vec[[vn]]] == 1, RGBColor[228/255, 26/255, 2/255], 
     Sign[vec[[vn]]] == -1, RGBColor[55/255, 126/255, 184/255]], 
   {EdgeForm[Thickness[Small]], Disk[{x, y}, Abs[vec[[vn]]]^(1/2), {θ0, θ1}]}}]

Show[
  Table[
    EVDisk[
      vectors[[n]], 
      m, 
      Which[
        n == 1 || n == 3, 1, 
        n == 2 || n == 4, 3], 
      If[n == 1 || n == 2, 1, -1], 
      (m - 1)*2*Pi/Length[vsorted[[n]]], 
      m*2*Pi/Length[vsorted[[n]]]], 
    {m, 1, Length[vsorted]}, {n, 1, Length[vsorted]}], 
  FrameTicks -> None, Frame -> True]
```

Which looks something like this (apart from the legend)

[image]

But what I want it to look like is

[image]

I made the second image in photoshop, but its tedious and kind of screws up the quality. So I'm wondering if someone could help me out on where to start with doing this inside *Mathematica* itself. I'm honestly not even sure if it possible, but I guess there must be a clever way to do it, probably part of it in the definition of EVDisk (the 1-4 part) I suppose.

Could anyone help me start?

Comment: regarding the quality - If you export the image as eps and then open it in photoshop with 300 resolution, do your edit and then save as jpg, you would get a much better quality final image.

Comment: Did you try to use `Text`?

Comment: Maybe you should also look into `SectorChart`.

Comment: The definition of `vsorted` is missing. Is it the same as `vectors`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like

```
{Black, Text[Style[vn, 16, Bold],
  {x + .3 Cos[(θ0 + θ1)/2], y + .3 Sin[(θ0 + θ1)/2]}]}}
```

to print `vn` in font Bold with fontsize 16, located near $(x,y)$, at distance $0.3$ in direction $(\theta_0+\theta_1)/2$.

For instance:

```
EVDisk[vec_, vn_, x_, y_, θ0_, θ1_] := 
 Graphics[{Which[Sign[vec[[vn]]] == 1, 
    RGBColor[228/255, 26/255, 2/255], Sign[vec[[vn]]] == -1, 
    RGBColor[55/255, 126/255, 184/255]], {EdgeForm[Thickness[Small]], 
    Disk[{x, y}, Abs[vec[[vn]]]^(1/2), {θ0, θ1}]},
   {Black, 
    Text[Style[vn, 16, Bold], {x + .3 Cos[(θ0 + θ1)/2], 
      y + .3 Sin[(θ0 + θ1)/2]}]}}
  ]
```